# Process Runtime execute parallel using java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have three python scripts which I am calling using Process Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path") as follows:

```
String abc= "C:\\Python27\\bin\\python.exe D:\\abc.py";
String efg="C:\\Python27\\bin\\python.exe D:\\efg.py";
callpy pyexc = new callpy();
pyexc.callpyQ(abc);
pyexc.callpyQ(efg);
```

**callpy class:**

```
public class callpy {
 public  void callpyQ (String path) throws Exception {
    Process p = null;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
   }
 }
```

As per the above code it is executing sequentially one by one and is taking more time for the program.

Is there a way i can call these process parallelly using multi thread to avoid minimize the time.
If so please suggest the code how to do it?

Comment: @Mena : Could you please post some code so that it will be useful for me to understand

Comment: `abc.py` is not an executable binary. You have to construct the full command that calls the Python interpreter. So it's not true that your posted code "is executing sequentially", it's not executing at all. Plus, \ in a string literal will escape the next char. Is this your real code?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : You are right. As you know, we can not run a process with out the executable binary. I have edited my code in the question.

Comment: What do your python scripts output? If it's anything more than a line, you'll get them blocked because you don't drain their `stdout` from Java. You should instead use the `ProcessBuilder` and its `inheritIo()` method. Other than that, your processes will run concurrently just the way you wrote it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : Pls suggest the best possible solution to run concurrently .

Comment: Please follow my suggestions above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122679/discussion-between-user4047127-and-marko-topolnik).

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik for your quick solution. I will try as mentioned with ProcessBuilder

Answer (score -1):

Make `callpy` a thread:

```
public class callpy extends Thread{
 private String path;

 public callpy(String p) {
        path=p;
 }

 public  void run()  {
   try {
    Process p = null;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
    p.waitFor();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //somthing ....
  }
 }
}
```

and run the threads in the `main`:

```
String abc= "C:\\Python27\\bin\\python.exe D:\\abc.py";
String efg="C:\\Python27\\bin\\python.exe D:\\efg.py";
callpy p1 = new callpy(abc);
callpy p2 = new callpy(efg);
p1.start();
p2.start();
//do something ....
p1.join();
p2.join();
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness @MarkoTopolnik. I modified it. Now it is not ridiculous!

Comment: Indeed. Now remove the threads and you have the same behavior. Then you can just delete the whole answer because at that point the code is identical to OP's.